# Timecode referenced from computer clock

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I basically want to press a button, that starts timecode at 30fps. (called every 1/30th of a second). I want the timecode to be referenced to the clock built in to the computer. I could easily get the current time in HH:mm:ss using NSDate, but I need the counter to start from zero and implement frames- formatted like HH:mm:ss:ff

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CVDisplayLink` to generate a pulse with the video card's accuracy, this will be much more accurate than an `NSTimer` or a dispatch queue.  CoreMedia/CoreVideo also talks SMPTE natively.

```
CVReturn MyDisplayCallback(CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink,
  const CVTimeStamp *inNow,
  const CVTimeStamp *inOutputTime,
  CVOptionFlags flagsIn,
  CVOptionFlags *flagsOut,
  void *displayLinkContext) {

    CVSMPTETime timecodeNow = inNow->smpteTime; // it's that easy!

    DoStuffWith(timecodeNow); // you might have to modulo this run a bit if the display framerate is greater than 30fps.

    return kCVReturnSuccess;
}

CVDisplayLinkRef _link;
CVDisplayLinkCreateWithCGDisplay(CGMainDisplayID(),&_link);
CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(_link, MyDisplayCallback, NULL);
CVDisplayLinkStart(_link);
```

EDIT: After playing with this a bit, I've noticed that the SMPTE fields from the displaylink aren't getting filled out, but OTOH the host time is accurate.  Just use:

```
inNow->videoTime / inNow->videoTimeScale;
```

to obtain the number of seconds uptime, and

```
inNow->videTime % inNow->videoTimeScale
```

to get the remainder.

Here's as far as I got:

```
@implementation JHDLTAppDelegate

CVReturn MYCGCallback(CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink,
                      const CVTimeStamp *inNow,
                      const CVTimeStamp *inOutputTime,
                      CVOptionFlags flagsIn,
                      CVOptionFlags *flagsOut,
                      void *displayLinkContext) {


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        JHDLTAppDelegate *obj = (__bridge JHDLTAppDelegate *)displayLinkContext;

        uint64_t seconds = inNow->videoTime / inNow->videoTimeScale;
           [obj.outputView setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"days: %llu/hours: %llu/seconds: %llu (%llu:%u)",
                                          seconds / (3600 * 24),
                                           seconds / 3600,
                                           seconds,
                                          inNow->videoTime, inNow->videoTimeScale]];


    });

    return kCVReturnSuccess;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    CVDisplayLinkCreateWithCGDisplay(CGMainDisplayID(), &_ref);
    CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(_ref, MYCGCallback, (__bridge void *)self);
    CVDisplayLinkStart(_ref);
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    CVDisplayLinkStop(_ref);
    CVDisplayLinkRelease(_ref);
}

@end
```

Comment: Awesome! Question, where is _ref coming from?

Comment: Is this better than finding a way to display the SMPTE time code using coreVideo?

Comment: Oh sorry, `_ref` is `_link`, I was copying and pasting from my test project...  I suspect there is a quick way of getting a CVTimeSTamp to give you a proper smpteTime field, but my day job is keeping me from completing my research :)  For now I would take an NSDate and convert it into a SMPTE frame count from midnight, offset that against the uptime, yada yada divmod...

Comment: Ok cool! One more question, and then I'll be done - what frameworks are required for this? I'm getting some mach-o linker errors. I imported AVFoundation

Comment: I'd upvote this a thousand times if I could - thank you so much for taking the time to do this.

Comment: I've been stuck for quite a while, and I think once I get this going, it'll be exactly what I need.

Comment: You need CoreVideo and CoreGraphics.  I'll betcha either CoreMedia or QTKit can help translate with the SMPTE translation.  Also this `dispatch_async()` in this code is a little perilous since it might overload the queue...

Answer (score 0):

This should work using an NSTimer object and doing the visual updates in the invocation. You can set the timer to fire every 3.3333 milliseconds. The only problem I see is over very long stretches, the timecode will be slightly off. Also, if this is video related, be careful because some video is encoded at 24 fps. I would then have a counter do a +1 in the method fired by the timer unless counter = 30, then I would have it reset to 1. You should be able to initialize an NSDateFormatter object with a custom format string to insert the current time and your counter variable in the format you want to display to the user.

Comment: I suspect that the NSTimer, if told to fire every 10.0/3.0 milliseconds, would be as accurate as the clock.

Comment: NSTimer isn't accurate enough for me.